# Adding Multiple TextView's to CollectionView in Tabrisjs

Tags: android, tabris, tabris-js

I'm able to easily add Widgets to CollectionView, but I can't seem to add more than one Widget type. I'm trying to add 2 TextView's. Here's what I got so far, it **only** outputs the firstName twice. (*this runs in Playground*)

Also, is it possible to add events to each TextView? like:
`.on('tap', () => {`

I do see how the `.on('select',`works, on the Collection View, but I want to add event to each individual TextView's

Thanks.

[image: Screenshot showing no last name]

```js
// Create a collection view, initialize its cells and fill it with items
const {CollectionView, Composite, ImageView, TextView, ui} = require('tabris');

let people = [
  ['Bob', 'Smith',],
  ['Fred', 'Jones'],
  ['James', 'Mackay'],
].map(([firstName, lastName]) => ({firstName, lastName}));

new CollectionView({
  left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0,
  itemCount: people.length,
  cellHeight: 56,

  createCell: () => {
    let cell = new Composite();

    new TextView({
      left: 30, top: 10,
      alignment: 'left'
    })
    .appendTo(cell);

    let txvLastName = new TextView({
      left: 50, top: 25,
      alignment: 'right'
    })
    .appendTo(cell);
    return cell;
  },
  updateCell: (cell, index) => {
    let person = people[index];
    cell.apply({
      TextView: {text: person.firstName},
      txvLastName: {text: person.lastName},
    });
  }
}).on('select', ({index}) => console.log('selected', people[index].firstName))
  .appendTo(ui.contentView);
```

Comment: I see a GitHub closed ticket https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues/1646 - *The children of a CollectionView are not a valid return value and should not be used. Since you are reusing the cells in the CV you can not access the widgets outside of the updateCells method.* So, I don't think I can get events on widgets inside CV.

Comment: You can, but remember that you're not operating on children of the CollectionView itself.  A CollectionView is comprised of the number of cells that fit on the screen, and as you scroll up and down the list the content is updated based on the cells that are visible on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [apply](http://docs.tabris.com/latest/selector.html#the-apply-method) method takes a Widget selector, which works similarly to CSS selectors and are documented at the aforementioned link.  You are referencing a JavaScript variable, which is not supported and not in scope in the `updateCell` callback function.

I would update your `createCell` callback so that each of the elements has a distinct [class](http://docs.tabris.com/latest/api/Widget.html#class) on them and reference that in your `updateCell` callback:

```
createCell: () => {
  let cell = new Composite();

  new TextView({
    left: 30, top: 10,
    class: 'firstName',
    alignment: 'left'
  }).appendTo(cell);

  new TextView({
    left: 50, top: 25,
    class: 'lastName',
    alignment: 'right'
  }).appendTo(cell);
  return cell;
},
updateCell: (cell, index) => {
  let person = people[index];
  cell.apply({
    '.firstName': {text: person.firstName},
    '.lastName': {text: person.lastName},
  });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks, now I'll see if I can get an event if someone clicks on lastName.